# Redux-form: keepDirtyOnReinitialize causes form to retain values also after unmount

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Using redux-form here. Part of the form is inited asyncronously after an ajax request (a list of items in a select) that depends on what the user selected on a separate field.

To achieve this I put the new items in the `initialValues` and I `enableReinitialize: true`. The select pre-fills properly and all is good.

But since I want to retain the other values that the user might have added in the form, I also `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true`.

So far so good.

The problem is that if the user navigates back to another page (without submitting the form) I would like to clear the all form and start from scratch.
It seems that the form is correctly destroyed on unmount but when we navigate back to the form again, the previous values are retained because of the `keepDirty...`

Should the unmounting of the form beat the `keepDirty`? Otherwise is it the only option to manually cleanup the form before navigating back to the other page or am I missing a simpler way?

Comment: If `destroyOnUnmount` is set to `true` the form should usually destroy the forms state when it gets unmounted. Are you sure, the form component really gets unmounted correctly and not just being hidden? If you debug with `redux-devtools` and inspect the state is it really deleted when you navigate back?

Comment: I see in the redux actions the action `DESTROY` and the form disappears from the state. But when I navigate back to the form, the form retains the previous values (I guess because of the `keepDirty...`

Comment: Are you able to get a codesandbox showing the issue?

Comment: So if the form values are deleted from the store where does it take the dirty values from to re-init the form? I created a sandbox with your setup and could not reproduce the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/ol6r3r2oqy If you try and unmount the form all  values are clean but you can still pass new initialValues to it.

Comment: Ok I got the problem, thanks for the suggestions. The 'dirty' values are actually taken from redux store so it is not the form retaining them but it is me retaining them and feeding them again to redux-form in the initial values. I need to rethink a bit my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the 'dirty' values are actually taken from redux store so it is not the form retaining them but it is me retaining them and feeding them again to redux-form in the initial values. I need to rethink a bit my code.